# Error 360: Cannot modify table or view used in subquery

Tags: sql, informix

INFORMIX-SE 7.32:

I'm getting error 360 when I try to execute the following statement:

```
update transaction
   set transaction.colx = (select tab1.cola from tab1)
 where transaction.num  = (select max(transaction.num) from transaction)
   and transaction.colx IS NULL;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why the Oracle and MySQL tags for this Informix-specific question?

Comment: @Tony- because the SQL update statement itself does not contain any INFORMIX-specific supersets and perhaps an experienced Oracle or MySQL programmer could answer the question (more audience).

Comment: But the error is an Informix error, and Oracle would not raise any error for this SQL, it would work just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to `UPDATE` the table `transaction` and read from the same table using `SELECT MAX` with the same query. You cannot do that.

[Subquery restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html)

> In general, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. For example, this limitation applies to statements of the following forms:
>   `DELETE FROM t WHERE ... (SELECT ... FROM t ...);`
>   `UPDATE t ... WHERE col = (SELECT ... FROM t ...);`
>   `{INSERT|REPLACE} INTO t (SELECT ... FROM t ...);`

Comment: So is there an alternative method for locating the max(transaction.num) in order to update it?

Comment: @Frank Why don't you run `select max(transaction.num) from transaction` first and use the value in the query.

Comment: @Frank: Amarghosh is correct - there are limitations in SE that are not present in IDS and other more modern and capable DBMS, and this is one of them. With IDS, you could use a SEQUENCE. With SE, you could create a one-row temporary table to hold the maximum and use that in the UPDATE statement. If, as I understand from other questions, you are primarily working with a single-user system, that will be safe enough. If you were dealing with a multi-user system (like most people have to), then you'd have to be a lot more worried about the TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) window for a change.