# SQL Error 360: Cannot modify table or view used in subquery

Tags: sql

I got the error

> Cannot modify table or view used in subquery

while executing this query.

Here `raw_str` in `my_table_view` has reference to `raw_str` in `my_table`.

Please suggest how to update the 'flag'.

```
update my_table
set flag = 'X'
where raw_str = (
                select raw_str from my_table_view
                where a_num in 
                    (
                        select num_id from num_table
                        where state not in (0, 1, 7, 99, 10, 11, 20, 21)
                        )
                )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What SQL dialect? For MS SQL servers, such opertaion should be allowed; for MS Access for example not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error 360: Cannot modify table or view used in subquery.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083609/error-360-cannot-modify-table-or-view-used-in-subquery)

Answer (score 0):

correct answer is dbms dependent, using MS-SQL 2000 2005 2008 and sybase you may use powerful 
**UPDATE FROM** with special clause **WITH(NOLOCK)** in order to force derived table "my_table_view" to be reused.

For other dbms (ORACLE Informix) you have to load subquery into **temp**

which is your platform ?

Ciao
Diego

Sql server 2005 2008 update from:

```
UPDATE B1
SET
    B1.PARAMETER_DS = 'UPDATED'
FROM
  B_PARAMETERS B1 WITH(ROWLOCK)
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT B2.* FROM 
 B_PARAMETERS B2 WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE FAMILY_ID = 5 ) B2
ON
    B1.PARAMETER_PK = B2.PARAMETER_PK
WHERE
    B2.PARAMETER_VL = 'X';
```

For Oracle:  Create Global Temporary Table [How to create a temporary table in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-oracle/2671546#2671546)
For Informix Create Temp Table: [Insert into temp values (select.... order by id)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263101/771061)

Comment: It seems that recent version of Informix IDS support **update from** behavior. In any case load into temp table is works alse on old stsndard engines.