# How can I Insert or Update a row with a value returned from a sub-query?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix, insert-update

EDIT: Looking for help from J. Leffler, Cheese Con Queso or anyone who knows Informix-SE well.

Informix-SE 4.11:

I have a table called 'cuadre' which is used to reconcile the cash drawer at the end of each business day (Monday thru Saturday). Once the drawer has been reconciled, the amount in the cash drawer is stored in column 'cu_sa_cash', the row is saved and the system is shutdowned, the store is closed for the day and we all go have some beers.. On the next business day, we start up the system, run an SQL procedure that creates (inserts) a new row in the cuadre table for that days postings and repeat the cycle again.

I would like for my SQL proc to INSERT the new row for the current day with the same cash in drawer amount that was stored in the previous business days row. Keep in mind that this is not SPL, as I'm still using SE 4.11.. So, the below SQL statements are the general idea of what I want to accomplish, but they don't work!.. Can you provide me with solution?.. Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO cuadre(cu_date,cu_en_dincaja)
     VALUES (TODAY,(SELECT cu_sa_cash
                      FROM cuadre
                     WHERE cu_date = (SELECT MAX(cu_date)
                                        FROM cuadre)));
```

or

```
INSERT INTO cuadre(cu_date)
     VALUES(TODAY);   

UPDATE cuadre
   SET cu_en_dincaja = (SELECT cu_sa_cash
                          FROM cuadre
                         WHERE cu_date = TODAY - 1)
 WHERE cu_date = TODAY;
```

Comment: This answer (for a question of yours!) says that you can't do that in Informix-SE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083609/error-360-cannot-modify-table-or-view-used-in-subquery

Comment: yep, forgot I had asked about this more than a year ago.. guess I'll have to use a temporary table to hold cu_sa_cash from max(cu_date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a temp table was the solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about informix in particular, but this is an alternative syntax...

```
INSERT INTO
  cuadre (
    cu_date,
    cu_en_dincaja
  )
SELECT
  TODAY,
  cu_sa_cash
FROM
  cuadre
WHERE
  cu_date = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(cu_date) FROM cuadre))
;
```

NOTE: This may return multiple rows if `cu_date` is not unique.

**EDIT** Added MySQL work around for reading from *and* writing to the same table.  Worth a test in Informix?

Comment: thanks!.. not to worry, cu_date has a unique index, as there's only one cash drawer to reconcile each day.. I'll give it a try

Comment: You cannot do that in Informix. You need to SELECT INTO TEMP t1, then INSERT SELECT * FROM t1 (There are a whole raft of ISOLATION LEVEL type issues with the single statement syntax, basically.)

Comment: In SE, you can't select from the table you're inserting into.  In IDS, you can, IIRC.  With SE, you'll have to go with a temporary table or something equivalent.

Comment: MySQL has a similar restriction on not being able to read from and insert into the same table.  There is a work around for that though, which seems bizarre but apparently works...  `WHERE cu_date = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(cu_date) FROM cuadre))`

Comment: The solution was to use a temp table.